# Overriding the ExpandDynamicLinks method in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, sitecore

I want the ExpandDynamicLinks method to act different from how it's acting out of the box.
We have created a solution which provides our customer a way to create subsites using branches very easy. However, when they use create links within an RTE field to items outside the context website the renderings won't render the pages correctly. I have a solution for this, but I want to implement it in the method that returns the correct markup for RTE fields. From what I've read this is the ExpandDynamicLinks method in the LinkManager. I want to know how I can plug in my own code. Is there a pipeline that renders the RTE fields and therefore calls the ExpandDynamicLinks method?

EDIT: I think it's the Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.ExpandLinks.Process(RenderFieldArgs): Void that I have to override.

Comment: You got it. You need to create your own ExpandLinks class and replace the one in the web.config with your custom one.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your hrefs look like in the rich-text field?  And then what gets rendered?  I've seen a couple of issues like this myself and might be able to help if you give me more specifics.  Also, are you sure the problem is happening during rendering?  The problems I've seen are actually the rich-text editor munging links after the user clicks on Accept.

Comment: I have already solved the issue :). I will provide my answer soon. Thanks for asking tho! upvoted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I override Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.ExpandLinks.Process(RenderFieldArgs) and implemented my own logic into it. This can be a solution to problems when rendering links from a RTE to another website that's in Sitecore.